# SQL query UPDATE statement syntax error

Tags: mysql

I need to run a SQL **UPDATE** query like below

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_1 = value_1
WHERE field_2 IN (
        SELECT t1.field_2
        FROM table_1 AS t1
            ,table_2 AS t2
        WHERE t2.field_3 = value_2
            AND t1.field_2 = t2.field_2
        );
```

But the issue is its is howing error like-

*You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause*

When I am running sub-query alone and putting its reslut in main query, then I am getting the results. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, MySQL can't update and select the same table at the same time. But with another subquery in the middle you can do it anyway

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET field_1 = value_1 
where field_2 in 
(
  select * from
  (
    SELECT t1.field_2 
    from table_1 as t1
    join table_2 as t2 on t2.field_3 = value_2 
    and t1.field_2= t2.field_2
  ) tmp
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the point of the additional sub-query level?

Comment: @juergen d, thanks a lot, it worked like a charm, but please explain what is the use of additonal sub-query level?

Comment: The use is that you create a temp table with it and don't need to select from the table you are updating directly.

Comment: Thanks @juergend, thats great